# Checking if a WPF app is being run from within visual studio

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

I have a WPF app which calls some WCF services which are in a separate project in the same solution.  When this app is deployed these WCF services are hosted using a windows service running on the same machine (they need to be hosted outside of the main app).

I have some code which checks the status of the windows services on startup however I only want this to run when the app is deployed, not when I am running it from within Visual Studio - is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use the [DesignerProperties.IsInDesignMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.isindesignmode.aspx) property. But this just tells you if your code is running in the context of the Visual Studio designer (i.e. while designing XAML files).

You can use the [Debugger.IsAttached](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.isattached.aspx) property to see if a debugger is attached while your application is running.

Otherwise, you're best bet would be to wrap your checks in a #if-#endif and define a symbol in release builds to include your checks.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy if you use ClickOnce:

```
if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
{
}
```